# Allocation of memory at start-up

Tags: delphi, memory

I am using Delphi 10.  One of my programs reads a lot of data from disk on start up.  When I run it the first time it might take up to a minute to complete the initial task.  I shut the program down and start it again.  Now the same task is completed in 10 seconds.  Why is this so?  Can I programatically free memory before starting the task to achieve a short start up in the first place?

Comment: `"Can I programatically free memory before starting the task to achieve a short start up in the first place?"` You're making a very false assumption about *why* your program is behaving the way it is. This is the #1 way to waste *a lot* of time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because of Windows file system caching. The first file access is slow, but Windows loads information into the cache. When your app then exists and is run immediately again, the data is read from the cache instead of the disk. It has nothing to do with memory allocation; this is part of the operating system's behavior.

Without any code, it's pretty much impossible to suggest anything you can do to improve the performance of your application.

Comment: First thing to check would be how many forms are auto-created in the dpr. Auto-creating many more than the main form always is a foolproof way of slowing down the startup of any application.

Comment: @Marjan: I don't agree, for two reasons: 1) From the question: "One of my programs **reads a lot of data from disk on start up**.", and 2) "I shut the program down and start it again. Now the same task is completed in 10 seconds.". The question clearly indicates lots of disk I/O, and since .dfm streaming uses resources (which I don't think are cached between executions of the app) the autocreate forms performance shouldn't change things between successive runs.

Comment: No, the resources are probably not be cached, but wouldn't the entire exe be in the file cache, especially after it has been read front to end to load all these dfm resources the first time around...

Comment: It would depend. Ihe resources might indeed be cached on application startup, but then replaced by the act of reading lots of data from disk.

Comment: Ah well, without seeing the source code I guess we both can only keep guessing... :-)

Comment: Thanks Ken. Your explanation makes sense. I will leave things as they are.